# Parametric asymptotic test for Poisson Distributed random sample

Tags: statistics

I am exercising for my stochastic course and cannot find an answer to this question.
We suppose the number of car crashes in a city is poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda > 0$. In the last couple of years the mean number of car crashes per year was 15. Last year the mean number of car crashes was only 10. Test if its legal to say the car crash rate sank. Test for the level $\alpha = 0.05$ die zero Hypothesis $H_0 \; : \; \lambda \ge 15$ to the alternative $h_1 : \lambda < 15$ using an asymptotic test.

I tried applying samples from our course script but that didnt work. I am confused about the null hypothesis not being in the form $\lambda = 15$ that means its a composite hypothesis so i tried to estimate to get a test working for all $\lambda \in H_0$, but couldnt come to a good result.

I fruther know by the central strong limit theorem and theorem of slutsky, for any given set of iid random var $(X-1,\dots,X_n)$, $X_i \tilde{ } Poi(\lambda)$ we have 
$$\sqrt{n} \frac{\bar{X}_n-\lambda}{\sqrt{X_n}} \to_{d} N(0,1)$$

Please tell me how to do this or hint me the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X \sim POIS(15),$ then $P(X \le 10) = 0.118.$ Hardly, astonishing.
Not significant at the 5% level.

```
 ppois(10, 15)
 ## 0.1184644
```

A normal approximation to Poisson with such a small mean seems
a bit risky. Especially, when there is no need for an approximation.

In any case, if you're (correctly) assuming $\lambda = 15$ for the null
distribution, then $\sigma = \sqrt{15}$
in the denominator; no need to estimate it as $\sqrt{\bar X}.$

Note: If you insist on the normal approximation, then the P-value is about 10%, still not significant.

```
 pnorm(10, 15, sqrt(15))
 ## 0.0983528
```

Closer to correct with continuity correction, about 12.3%:

```
 pnorm(10.5, 15, sqrt(15))
 ## 0.1226391
```

Below: Blue bars for POIS(15).  Maroon curve: approximating normal density.

[image]